# SQL concatenate if value not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to write a SQL that will return me data in specific format. This is the query.

```
SELECT F_NAME, M_NAME, L_NAME 
WHERE PERSON_DEPT = 'HR'
```

I want the result in this format:

```
FirstName:Scott,MiddleName:Rotham,LastName:Tiger
```

If there is no middle name, it should be:

```
FirstName:Scott,LastName:Tiger
```

If there is no first name, it should be:

```
MiddleName:Rotham,LastName:Tiger
```

If there is no last name, it should be:

```
FirstName:Scott,MiddleName:Rotham
```

If all three columns are empty, it should be nothing.

I am trying to do something like below, but I need null (empty) check for M_NAME and L_NAME as well.

```
SELECT (CASE
   WHEN F_NAME IS NOT NULL          
   THEN CONCAT(F_NAME,M_NAME,L_NAME)
   ELSE '' 
END) AS EMPLOYEE
FROM PERSON
WHERE PERSON_DEPT = 'HR'
```

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server and PL\SQL here, which is Oracle's propriety dialect. What RDBMS are you really using? Also, your query is missing a `FROM`.

Comment: I am using SQL Server @GordonLinoff

Comment: If all three fields are empty what should the output be? The post seems incomplete.

Comment: All fields empty will just return a blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, including correct handling of commas if any of the fields are empty.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PERSON_DEPT
CREATE TABLE #PERSON_DEPT(F_NAME VARCHAR(10), M_NAME VARCHAR(10), L_NAME VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #PERSON_DEPT (F_NAME, M_NAME, L_NAME) VALUES 
('Max', 'V', 'O'),
('John', null, 'Doe'),
('Alex', 'D', null),
('Spencer', null, null),
(null, null, null)

SELECT 
    COALESCE('FirstName:' + F_NAME, '') + (CASE WHEN M_NAME IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ',' END) + 
    COALESCE('MiddleName:' + M_NAME, '') + (CASE WHEN L_NAME IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ',' END) + 
    COALESCE('LastName:' + L_NAME, '') 
FROM #PERSON_DEPT
```

The result:

| Full Name |
| --- |
| FirstName:**Max**,MiddleName:**V**,LastName:**O** |
| FirstName:**John**,LastName:**Doe** |
| FirstName:**Alex**,MiddleName:**D** |
| FirstName:**Spencer** |
| *empty* |

Answer (score 4):

You can use `concat_ws` which ignores nulls instead of `concat` which doesn't. Larnu has a good solution if your DB version doesn't support this.

```
concat_ws(',', f_name, m_name, l_name)
```

Comment: The `COALESCE` is pointless here, `CONCAT_WS` can't return a `NULL` value. `SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',CONVERT(varchar(10),NULL),CONVERT(varchar(10),NULL),CONVERT(varchar(10),NULL))` would return `''`.

Comment: @Larnu Oh boy! You're right

Answer (score 2):

On a recent version of SQL Server (2017+) you can use `CONCAT_WS` to avoid `NULL` concatenation and add the delimiter, but also make use of said `NULL` concatenation with the `+` concatenation operator:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',N'FirstName:' + F_NAME, N'MiddleName:' + M_NAME, N'LastName:' + L_NAME)
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

If you're on an older version of SQL Server, however, then you can use the older method of prefixing all the values with the delimiter and using `STUFF` to remove the first one:

```sql
SELECT STUFF(CONCAT(N',FirstName:' + F_NAME, N',MiddleName:' + M_NAME, N',LastName:' + L_NAME),1,1,'')
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be

```
select 
case when f_name is not null and m_name is not null and l_name is not null 
     then 'Firstname:' + f_name + ',' + 'MiddleName:' + m_name + ',' + 'LastName:' + l_name 
     when f_name is not null and m_name is null and l_name is not null 
     then 'Firstname:' + f_name + ',' + 'LastName:' + l_name  
     when f_name is null and m_name is not null and l_name is null 
     then 'Middlename:' + m_name + ',' + 'MiddleName:' + m_name
     when f_name is null and m_name is null and l_name is null 
     then null 
else null end result
    from t
```

You might extend the logic in any way you want.

Demo

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ab3f8f671685e9d94d85bbd9bc8ffb7)